# Android - Live data not working with recyclerview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, design-patterns, android-livedata

LiveData is not triggering. There are many livedata that I ran in the same fragment but one of them just didn't work. I have no idea what the problem is.

**ViewModel.kt (Part of the code has been reduced.)**

```kotlin
class MyAccountViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _dataUser = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val dataUser: LiveData<User>
        get() = _dataUser

    private val _userState = MutableLiveData<UserViewState>()
    val userState: LiveData<UserViewState>
        get() = _userState

    private val _storiesState = MutableLiveData<StoriesViewState>()
    val storiesState: LiveData<StoriesViewState>
        get() = _storiesState

    private val _dataStories = MutableLiveData<List<Stories>>()
    val dataStories: LiveData<List<Stories>>
        get() = _dataStories

    private val _navigateToStories = MutableLiveData<Long>()
    val navigateToStories: LiveData<Long>
        get() = _navigateToStories

    fun openUserStories(userId: Long) {
        _navigateToStories.postValue(userId)
    }

 }
```

**Fragment**

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
      observe(viewModel.dataUser, ::onViewUserDataChanged) //WORKING
      observe(viewModel.userState, ::onViewUserStateChanged) //WORKING
      observe(viewModel.dataStories, ::onViewStoriesDataChanged) //WORKING 
      observe(viewModel.storiesState, ::onViewStoriesStateChanged) //WORKING
      observe(viewModel.navigateToStories, ::onViewEvent) //NOT WORKING
}

 private fun onViewEvent(viewEvent: Long) {
       findNavController().navigate(
          MyAccountFragmentDirections.
           actionMyAccountFragmentToMediaShowFragment(viewEvent)
        )
 }
```

**observe() Method:**

```kotlin
fun <T> LifecycleOwner.observe(liveData: LiveData<T>, observer: (T) -> Unit) {
    liveData.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { t -> observer(t) }
    })
}


fun <T> LifecycleOwner.observe(liveData: MutableLiveData<T>, observer: (T) -> Unit) {
    liveData.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { t -> observer(t) }
    })
}
```

**onClick with DataBinding (Part of the code has been reduced.):**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.openUserStories(stories.id)}"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Here are the recyclerview items that I applied the onClick method.**

[image]

Comment: LiveData is for state, not events. You need to use an approach such as [`SingleLiveEvent`](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) if you want to misuse LiveData for events.

Comment: I have also tried using SingleLiveData. It didn't work again. Actually that's not the problem. the problem is that the observer is not triggered.

Comment: maybe its not related but use ```postValue``` when setting the value from a background thread and ```setValue``` when calling from a UI thread, In your case its the second,

Comment: also are u sure that the click event is getting triggered?

Comment: Yes, it triggers. I tried. I have no idea what the problem is. There is nothing I haven't tried.

Comment: It could be several things, if you still have this problem. Maybe you forgot to bind the `viewModel`-instance to the layout-xml. Or your `LifecycleOwner.observe`-extension is not working, since you use the `fragment`-instance instead of its `viewLifecycleOwner`. Also I think you have to call `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner` first in `onViewCreated`. If it still does not work, usually I debug the generated databinding-code that actually calls `viewModel.openUserStories()` and step through it to see where it breaks (you may have to set the breakpoint earlier in this Impl.java file).